# Does anyone know how to update the database using text boxes.in vb.net asp?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, textbox, updating

Please help me. I have a data source which populates text boxes on page load so as to update them like so….this works but the update does not

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dv As DataView = DirectCast(SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
    For Each drv As DataRowView In dv
        txtCompName.Text = drv("companyName").ToString()
        txtAddressLine1.Text = drv("addressLine1").ToString()
        txtAddressLine2.Text = drv("addressLine2").ToString()
        txtTown.Text = drv("companyTown").ToString()
        txtCompanyPostCode.Text = drv("customerPostcode").ToString()
        txtCompanyTelephone.Text = drv("companyTelephone").ToString()
        txtCompanyWebAdd.Text = drv("webAddress").ToString()
        ' ddlCompanyStatus.Text = drv("companyStatus").ToString()
        ddlQuoteStatus.Text = drv("companyQuoteStatus").ToString()
        txtCompanyNotes.Text = drv("companyNotes").ToString()
        txtRegion.Text = drv("companyRegion").ToString()
        ddlLeadSource.Text = drv("leadSource").ToString()
        txtSICCode.Text = drv("SICCode").ToString()
        ' txt.Text = drv("dateEntered").ToString()
        ddlEnterMadeBy.Text = drv("employeeAddedCustomer").ToString()
        ddlAddressType.Text = drv("addressType").ToString()
        txtCompBecameCustomer.Text = drv("dateBecameACustomer").ToString()


        lblActivityDate.Text = Date.Now
        lblActivityTime.Text = TimeOfDay

    Next
End Sub
```

This is the data source I have added an update sql statement just to try a different way.

```
</table>   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" OnUpdating=" btnAddCustomer_Click" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [customerTable] WHERE ([customerId] = @customerId)" UpdateCommand="Update customerTable set companyName = @companyName , addressLine1 = @addressLine1, addressLine2 = @addressLine2, companyTown = @companyTown, customerPostcode = @customerPostcode, companyTelephone = @companyTelephone, webAddress = @webAddress, companyStatus = @companyStatus, companyQuoteStatus = @companyQuoteStatus, companyNotes = @companyNotes, companyRegion = @companyRegion, leadSource = @leadSource, SICCode = @SICCode, employeeAddedCustomer = @employeeAddedCustomer, addressType = @addressType, dateBecameACustomer = @dateBecameACustomer where customerId =@customerId
">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="customerId" QueryStringField="customerId" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="companyName" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="addressLine1" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="addressLine2" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="companyTown" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="customerPostcode" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="companyTelephone" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="webAddress" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="companyStatus" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="companyQuoteStatus" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="companyNotes" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="companyRegion" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="leadSource" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="SICCode" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="employeeAddedCustomer" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="addressType" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="dateBecameACustomer" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="customerId" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and tried manually using this code behind

```
Protected Sub btnAddCustomer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateCustomer.Click

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\C………………..mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    ' 

    Dim strCustomerId, strName, strAddressLine1, strAddressLine2, strCompanyTown, strCustomerPostcode, strCompanyTelephone, strWebAddress, strCompanyStatus, strCompanyQuoteStatus, strCompanyNotes, strRegion, strLeadSource, strSICCode, strEmployeeAddedCustomer, strAddressType As String

    Dim strDateBecameCustomer, strDateEntered As Date

    strCustomerId = Request.QueryString("customerId").ToString
    strName = txtCompName.Text
    strAddressLine1 = txtAddressLine1.Text
    strAddressLine2 = txtAddressLine2.Text
    strCompanyTown = txtTown.Text
    strcustomerPostcode = txtCompanyPostCode.Text
    strcompanyTelephone = txtCompanyTelephone.Text
    strwebAddress = txtCompanyWebAdd.Text
    strCompanyStatus = ddlCompanyStatus.Text
    strcompanyQuoteStatus = ddlQuoteStatus.Text
    strCompanyNotes = txtCompanyNotes.Text
    strRegion = txtRegion.Text
    strLeadSource = ddlLeadSource.Text
    strSICCode = txtSICCode.Text
    ' strDateEntered = "" does not change
    strEmployeeAddedCustomer = ddlEnterMadeBy.Text
    strAddressType = ddlAddressType.text
    ' strDateBecameCustomer = txtCompBecameCustomer.Text
    '
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "Update customerTable set companyName = @companyName , addressLine1 = @addressLine1, addressLine2 = @addressLine2, companyTown = @companyTown, customerPostcode = @customerPostcode, companyTelephone = @companyTelephone, webAddress = @webAddress, companyStatus = @companyStatus, companyQuoteStatus = @companyQuoteStatus, companyNotes = @companyNotes, companyRegion = @companyRegion, leadSource = @leadSource, SICCode = @SICCode, employeeAddedCustomer = @employeeAddedCustomer, addressType = @addressType where customerId = 1" 

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerId", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strCustomerId.ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtCompName.Text.ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@addressLine1", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtAddressLine1.Text.ToString()                'strAddressLine1.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@addressLine2", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strAddressLine2.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyTown", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strCompanyTown.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerPostcode", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strCustomerPostcode.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyTelephone", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strCompanyTelephone.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@webAddress", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strWebAddress.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyStatus", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strCompanyStatus.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyQuoteStatus", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strCompanyQuoteStatus.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyNotes", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strCompanyNotes.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyRegion", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strRegion.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@leadSource", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strLeadSource.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SICCode", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strSICCode.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@employeeAddedCustomer", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strEmployeeAddedCustomer.ToString
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@addressType", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strAddressType.ToString
    ' cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateBecameACustomer", SqlDbType.Text).Value = strDateBecameCustomer



    cmd.Connection = conn
    ' Try
    conn.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ' Catch
    ' Finally
    conn.Close()
    'End Try
    ' End If

End Sub
```

I have also tried  using the following

```
    'cmd.CommandText = "Update customerTable set companyName = @companyName where customerId = 1" ' & strCustomerId

    ' cmd.CommandText = "Update customerTable set companyName = '" & txtCompName.Text & "' "
    'cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@companyName", txtCompName.Text))

    'cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@companyName", DirectCast(txtCompName, TextBox).Text))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
addressLine1, addressLine2, companyTown, customerPostcode, companyTelephone, webAddress, companyStatus, companyQuoteStatus, companyNotes, companyRegion, leadSource, SICCode, dateEntered, employeeAddedCustomer)VALUES('" + strName + "','" + strAddressLine1 + "','" + strAddressLine2 + "','" + strCompanyTown + "','" + strcustomerPostcode + "','" + strcompanyTelephone + "','" + strwebAddress + "','" + strcompanyStatus + "','" + strcompanyQuoteStatus + "','" + strcompanyNotes + "' ,'" + strRegion + "' ,'" + strLeadSource + "' ,'" + strSICCode + "' ,'" + strDateCompanyEntered + "' ,'" + employeeAddedCustomer + "')"
```

Comment: Please format your question. Also, what is the problem? Do you get an error message?

Comment: what `ERROR` you are getting ?

Comment: no error and no update in database